# How to find the closing bracket in NuSphere PhpEd?

Tags: branch, phped

I use NuSphere PhpEd IDE and I'd like to know, is there a way to find the closing bracket, like in Eclipse (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>   Go to Matching Bracket   Helps to find the closing bracket of lengthy if-else statements.). Is there a similar shortcut in phpEd?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>

To define your own shortcuts go to *Tools -> Settings -> Editor shortcuts*

Answer (score 2):

To find the closing bracket on windows you will need to do the following :

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Now <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> are working with bookmarks like in VS.
To jump to matching bracket, you have to press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, not too comfortable, but indeed you can define you own on *Tools->Settings->IDE Shortcuts* page.